# The Quotient exponential operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

I have a question if you don't mind. I have the following quotient operator:
$$\frac{1}{e^{d/dx}(f(x))}$$
Where $f$ is a smooth function on $R$. I would like to get rid of the denominator. IS there any formula that i Can found in your papers or other references and use it for this case? Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 4):

The exponentiated operator shifts $f$ by one unit in $x$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{1}{e^{d/dx} (f(x))} = \frac{1}{f(x+1)}
$$
It's not quite clear what is desired by "getting rid of the denominator" - the result just happens to be the reciprocal of $f$. You could define $g=1/f$ and have an expression without a fraction.

Comment: Where did you found this formula is this the developement of Taylor?

Comment: The shift operator is described here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator - you can also find some references there if you want to cite something.