# The exponential derivative operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Thank you very much for the interesting responses in my previous question [The Quotient exponential operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395922/the-quotient-exponential-operator).
I have another complicated formula related to the previous one in the following
$$
\exp\left[-x\bigg(\frac{d}{dx}\bigg)^{2}+\frac{d}{dx}\right]\big(f(x)\big).
$$
I would like to develop this equation and decompose it using a reference or a Book: I have found this kind of operators in G. Dattoli and A. Torre's works. I inform everyone that the two researchers produce many papers and Books in the fields of Physics and mathematics, so that is very difficult to search and find the required response within their large numbers of papers. If someone can help me I will be very grateful.
Respectful regards.

Comment: Depends how explicit an answer you're expecting. With higher derivatives like that in the exponent, you're generally going to get forms where the argument of $f$ contains derivatives, which may or may not be very useful (depends - if $f$ is itself exponential, that may then reduce to something simpler again). Alternatively, you might get answers in the form of series.

Comment: It's worth to notice that $$\left[-x(\frac{d}{dx})^{2}+\frac{d}{dx}\right]^2 = x^2(\frac{d}{dx})^{4}.$$

Comment: It's also worth noting that, if we denote $A=d/dx$ and $B=-x(d/dx)^2 $, then we have the specific algebra $[A,B]=-A^2 $.

Comment: f is not necesseraly exponential

Comment: I have done a mistake in the formula i must say

Comment: $$e^{-x(d/dx)^{2}-d/dx}(f(x))$$ What is the general form of this formula i have didn't notice it. I am so sorry.

Comment: Is it legitimate to decompose this form? I am so sorry for the mistake

Comment: The last formula that i gave in the comment that i am searching for

Comment: Correct the question, then, perhaps? It saves the reader from reading the comments. You can certainly adapt the remark of @MichaelEngelhardt to this case, and find how the algebra works out.

Comment: Formally, this would be $u(x,1)$, where $u(x,t)$ solves the equation $u_t=-xu_{xx}+u_x$ with initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$. However, this initial value problem is not well-posed, at least not for $x$ on the real line.

Comment: Something is odd about the question (and about the linked one). The first thing to do when you want to work with such an object is to actually specify how it is *defined*. If you would like to substitute differential operators into a scalar-valued function, this is typically done by means of *functional calculus*, which is an operator theoretic concept. But in order to use this concept, you first need to clarify in which way you understand the expression $-x (\frac{d}{dx})^2 + \frac{d}{dx}$ as an operator - i.e., you need to specify a surrounding Banach space and the domain of the operator.

Comment: [continued] Since you seem to be mainly interested in substituting (differerential) operators into the exponential function, you will probably be interested in the theory of $C_0$-semigroups (which can - very generally speaking - be seen as a special case of a functional calculus).